# Spring custom Startup Servlet without URL mapping gets invoked

Tags: spring-boot, servlets

I have migrated an application from a standard Java WEB project to Spring Boot. In the process I had to migrate also a Servlet that its main scope was to initialize some components (reading property files, etc).

The legacy code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>startupservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.name.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The new code:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<StartupServlet> startupServletBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<StartupServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<StartupServlet>(
            new StartupServlet());
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    return bean;
}
```

Doing so, the StartupServlet gets invoked when accessing any URL, messing with the app behavior.

As a workaround, I have added a dummy path in order the Servlet init code to be called, but never to get through the get and post methods.

I believe I am missing something from how Spring Boot is managing servlet declaration but I still did not find what.

[Edit] It is not a real issue, because, as per @jbx's comment, I should transform it into a `@Service`. But I just wanted to find out why Spring enables the servlet on every path by default or how I can inhibit this.

Comment: Use `new ServletRegistrationBean<StartupServlet>(new StartupServlet(), false, new String[]{});` instead of what you have now.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `StartupServlet` anyway? All the startup stuff is handled by spring under the hood. If you need to have anything initialised on startup just annotate it as a `@Component` or `@Service` and let Spring manage the bean for you. Configuration properties also have a special `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation, which takes care of loading properties etc. Given that you migrated to Spring Boot for a reason, take advantage of what the framework offers.

Comment: @jbx Thx, for the input ! It is true that I should make use of what Spring offers, but in a first step I wanted minimum changes to the code, in order not to impact functionality a lot. That's why I just moved the code and not refactor. Because I've noticed this strange behavior, I was wondering why is this difference between web.xml and Spring.I was expecting that if I do not set any path, the Servlet would not be accessible, but Spring makes it available everywhere.

Comment: Well Spring has its own lifecycle of its beans. In the classic Spring, when you had a web app `.war` Spring itself would have its own servlet (`DispatcherServlet`) which acts as the entry point. You can see how it would be in `web.xml` here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html. Spring Boot turns things a bit around, and it 'hosts' the servlet container (like Tomcat) embedded. Not sure how your code looks, and what Spring Boot is determining as useful to load and expose.